# How to access elements of elements inside an associative array in korn shell

Tags: arrays, shell, ksh

I have started scripting two weeks back and now I am trying to create a 3D array using associative array in korn shell script. I tried all possible combinations that i could think of without making the script very long, but I am not able to make any progress. I am trying to address individual element inside of associative array and I am not able to do that. I would really appreciate any help on this.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

typeset -A array_of_array              #array_of_array is associative

array_of_array=([array_index]="A B C D E"
           [A]="AA AAA AAAA"
           [B]="BB BBB BBBB"
           [C]="CC CCC CCCC"
           [D]="DD DDD DDDD"
           [E]="EE EEE EEEE"
          )

print_fun(){
        for INDEX in ${array_of_array["array_index"]};
        do
                echo "$INDEX --->"

                echo ${${array_of_array[$INDEX]}[0]} #this is incorrect instrn

                for ITEMS in ${array_of_array[$INDEX]}
                do
                        echo $'\t\t\t'$ITEMS
                done
        done
}
print_fun
```

I am trying to get a output like this:

```
A  --->  AA
         AAA
         AAAA

B  --->  BB
         BBB
         BBBB

C  --->  CC
         CCC
         CCCC
```

Comment: I've retagged your question for `ksh`, since `ksh` and `bash` have quite a few differences. (Most relevant here, `bash` does not allow nested arrays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an arrays of arrays; you have an array of *strings*.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

typeset -A array_of_array

# This associates another array with each key in the outer array
array_of_array=(
           [A]=(AA AAA AAAA)
           [B]=(BB BBB BBBB)
           [C]=(CC CCC CCCC)
           [D]=(DD DDD DDDD)
           [E]=(EE EEE EEEE)
          )

print_fun(){
        # Use this syntax for iterating over the keys of the outer array
        for INDEX in "${!array_of_array[@]}";
        do
                echo "$INDEX --->"

                # Use this syntax for accessing the elements
                # of the inner array associate with each key
                for ITEMS in "${array_of_array[$INDEX][@]}"
                do
                        echo $'\t\t\t'$ITEMS
                done
        done
}
print_fun
```

Comment: This script is not running, http://www.shellcheck.net/  shows errors. 
Also can we declare an associative array in the way it is shown above.
Can you please explain "${array_of_array[$INDEX][@]}" instruction

Comment: What version of `ksh` are you using? This works fine for me in `ksh` 93u+ 2012-08-01. `shellcheck` does not appear to support `ksh`.